# A command prompt start while I start main program

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple program. A command prompt window comes up in the background when starting my program. How can I fix it?

[image: this is screen shot of my program]

Comment: Or at least showing it; that is not standard behavior for a WinForms application

Comment: You started from the wrong template and have now wrangled it into working as a windows application? Try to start from an open Visual Studio instance with no solution loaded and describe the steps you've gone through to reach (a simplified version of) this state.

Comment: Can you post the code from your `Program.cs` class?  It should contain a `Main()` function with around 3 lines of code.

Comment: static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Go into your project properties (right click on project)

<kbd>Properties</kbd> => <kbd>Application</kbd> => <kbd>Output type</kbd>

Set it to "Windows Application" instead of "Console Application".

Comment: thanks.but It's not working

Comment: @Hamid "not working" is not a helpful description. Does it still show the console? Does it show an exception message? Does it get up from your computer, lie down on your couch and watch TV eating cheetos?

Comment: my program work correctly and there are not any errors. I only want to prevent command prompt window. this is at top of that: windows application\bin\release\windowsapplication.exe